# How is the new SO site revision managed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Before I read [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/stack-overflow-and-dvcs/) I noticed the revision had changed on SO from the SVN revision to 2010.4.23.1. Just switched to Mercurial from SVN myself and hit this same problem. We used to display the SVN revision on the site, but now that we have no true central repository, displaying a number that can be tied back to the source control system is a challenge.

How is the reverse date format for the site revision managed and then tied back to source?

Comment: This is almost a question for SO

Comment: I believe it **IS** a question for SO, not for meta

Answer (score 4):

But there *is* a number that can be tied back to the source control system.

```
[balpha@localhost unicorns-0-5]$ hg tip
changeset:   63:e2024788839c
tag:         tip
user:        balpha
date:        Wed Mar 31 21:29:16 2010 +0200
summary:     Add Stack Overflow message to the website
```

The `63` needn't be identical on clones of the repo, but the revision hash is.

Comment: Just​​​ the tip?​​​

Comment: The 63 is only valid as long as your central repo is never replaced, correct? I don't know why this would happen, but I suppose it could. This is what I decided to do with our source...but it bugs me. :)

Comment: @ranomore: Yes, it could. Never rely on the `63`. Rely on the `e20247...` -- that one identifies the changeset no matter what way it reached whichever repo. The idea of DVCS is that there is no real central repo -- it should be replaceable anytime.